# Clear Oracle session state

Tags: oracle, plsql

A database connection on Oracle can have session state that persists for the lifetime of the connection, i.e. in the form of package variables.

Is there a way of flushing/clearing all that state between calls during a connection without killing the connection and reestablishing a new connection.

I.e. consider a package variable first set in the package init, and later modified within some procedure in that package: how to "reset" the package so that multiple calls to the procedure from 1 connection always lead to a reinit of the package?

In general: how to "reset" any session state between execution of statements from a client on that connection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dbms_session.reset_package` is the closest I can think of. See this [tahiti link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sessio.htm#i1010767).

Comment: Thx! That should do it for package state (though it's unfortunate that this also clears any cached cursers). Apart from package vars, is there any other global session state (hence not cleared by above reset_package)?

Comment: Ah, `DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE()` is the same as `DBMS_SESSION.MODIFY_PACKAGE_STATE(DBMS_SESSION.FREE_ALL_RESOURCES)`, but there is also `DBMS_SESSION.MODIFY_PACKAGE_STATE(DBMS_SESSION.REINITIALIZE)` which does not free resources (taking performance hit), but reinits data. Great.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger I have tried all three from java JDBC, i.e: [callStmt = con.prepareCall("begin DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE; end;");
    callStmt.execute();] but they have no effect. Is there something I can add to ensure it is effective immediately

Answer (score 0):

Other than `dbms_session.reset_package` (proposed in René Nyffenegger's answer), which resets all packages, you'll have to write your own package procedure to reset the state of a single package only. The procedure would just set all package variables to NULL (or whatever is appropriate).

Comment: Yeo, doable, but error prone and dependent on developer / changing the package. My use case involves calling SPs from persistent (long-liven) frontend Websocket connections via a pool of database connections. Hence there is no 1:1 relation between Websocket frontend and database backend connections. I want to make sure no information leaks across different Websocket connections via global state on the database pool connections.